# How do I access the app engine admin interface when loading jetty in the Clojure repl

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure

Is there a way to get to the admin interface if I'm not using the `dev_appserver.sh` script and instead loading up jetty myself?

I'm doing this so that I can use the Clojure repl during development. While my application works as expected, there is nothing handling the `/_ad/admin` requests and so I can't get to the data store viewer or look at other admin stuff. Here's how I'm loading up the server in the repl: http://gist.github.com/491868.

I need to manually bind the handler for that route, but I'm not even sure what the handler is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the jetty application and the jetty library (my distinction)

The Jetty application knows how to read a config file, host servlets or WAR applications. This is similar to tomcat in that it provides you an admin interface with which you may interact with the jetty application, ie deploy applications to it.

The way you are using is via the API. In this mode you are responsible for defining routes and handlers for requests etc. This is a low-level approach suitable for simulating the Google App Engine environment (in fact, the GAE client-side mode does run on jetty). It doesn't include the admin interface you speak of since it is running in an environment (yours) with which it is unfamiliar and is not suited for.

You will however be able to do anything you could do in the web interface with api calls directly.